# Почему выводит [Object] в результате ?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
    , format = require('util').format;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/chat', function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;

    var collection = db.collection('test_insert');
    collection.remove({}, function(err, affected) {
        if (err) throw err;

        collection.insert({a: 2}, function(err, docs) {

            var cursor = collection.find({a: 2});
            cursor.toArray(function(err, results) {
                console.dir(results);
                // Let's close the db
                db.close();
            });
        });

    });
});
```

Вот простенький код по занесению данных в базе и их последующего вывода в консоль. Вот что получается в результате:

```
[ { _id: ObjectID { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: [Object] }, a: 2 } ]
```

Как сделать, чтобы вместо [Object] выводились значения ?

Answer (score 0):

Используй метод

```
ObjectId.toString()
//В твоем случае
results['_id'].toString()
```

Доки тут: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/ObjectId/
И тут: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString